# How to get array that contains dictonary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I want to get this array contains dictionary to pass in api.

Please check parameter result at end I get "\n"

```
[{"user_id":"46","e_id":"566","date_list":"2018\/04\/20","t_depo":" 0.0","mini":"200","real_earn":"-5000.0","mb_balance":"-4000.0","balance_for":"4000"}]
```

any idea?

I tried to send on api this way but not worked

```
var ary : [[String:String]] = []
        var mutableDictionary = [String: String]()
        var mutableArray:NSMutableArray!

            mutableDictionary.updateValue("\(appdel.dateSelected!)", forKey: "date_list")
            mutableDictionary.updateValue("\(user_id)", forKey: "user_id")
            mutableDictionary.updateValue("566", forKey: "e_id")
            mutableDictionary.updateValue("\(RupeesDepositeTotal.text!)", forKey: "t_depo")
            mutableDictionary.updateValue("300", forKey: "mini")
            mutableDictionary.updateValue("\(RealIncomeTF.text ?? "0")", forKey: "real_earn")
            mutableDictionary.updateValue("\(RealIncomeTF.text ?? "0")", forKey: "mb_balance")
            mutableDictionary.updateValue("\(newBalanceLabel.text ?? "0")", forKey: "balance_for")
            ary.append(mutableDictionary)


        mutableArray =  NSMutableArray(array: ary)


        print(mutableArray)
```

I pass parameter like this:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "insert": "0",
            "Data": "\(mutableArray!)"
        ]
```

This is my console when I print mutable array

```
(
        {
        "balance_for" = "-231.0";
        "date_list" = "2018/04/20";
        "e_id" = 566;
        "mb_balance" = 33;
        mini = 300;
        "real_earn" = 33;
        "t_depo" = 264;
        "user_id" = 46;
    }
)
```

when  I print parameters:

```
["insert": "0", "Data": "(\n        {\n        \"balance_for\" = \"-10.0\";\n        \"date_list\" = \"2018/04/20\";\n        \"e_id\" = 566;\n        \"mb_balance\" = 6;\n        mini = 300;\n        \"real_earn\" = 6;\n        \"t_depo\" = 16;\n        \"user_id\" = 46;\n    }\n)"]
```

Comment: `let array = [{"user_id":"46","e_id":"566","date_list":"2018\/04\/20","t_depo":" 0.0","mini":"200","real_earn":"-5000.0","mb_balance":"-4000.0","balance_for":"4000"}]` this is already an array containing a dict like you mentioned.

Comment: Don't use `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` in `Swift`.

Comment: `"Data": "\(mutableArray!)"` Don't use the description for setting the value. Just do `"Data": mutableArray` instead. Also, you seem to want JSON at some point, so use `JSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dict = [String: String]()  
dict["user_id"] = "46"  
dict["e_id"] ="566"  
dict["date_list"] = "2018/04/20"  
dict["t_depo"] = " 0.0"  
dict["mini"] = "200"  
dict["real_earn"] = "-5000.0"  
dict["mb_balance"] = "-4000.0"  
dict["balance_for"] = "4000"  
var dictArray = [dict];  
print(dictArray)
```

Comment: thanks for reply and it gave error i tried like this var dict = NSMutableDictionary() I get array with dictonary but I dont want in new line console [{
    "balance_for" = 4000;
    "date_list" = "2018/04/20";
    "e_id" = 566;
    "mb_balance" = "-4000.0";
    mini = 200;
    "real_earn" = "-5000.0";
    "t_depo" = " 0.0";
    "user_id" = 46;
}]
 I want the result like this ", comma" instead of new line or semicolon [{"user_id":"46","e_id":"566","date_list":"2018\/04\/20","t_depo":" 0.0","mini":"200","real_earn":"-5000.0","mb_balance":"-4000.0","balance_for":"4000"}]

Comment: Use latest swift version

Comment: I tried I get the result in this way : ["insert": "0", "Data": [["real_earn": "-5000", "balance_for": "4000", "t_depo": " 0.0", "date_list": "2018/04/25", "user_id": "46", "e_id": "566", "mini": "200", "mb_balance": "4000"]]]
but it didn't update the data when I checked in postman

Answer (score 0):

You do:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "insert": "0",
            "Data": "\(mutableArray!)"
        ]
```

What you are doing wrong:

```
"Data": "\(mutableArray!)"
```

That's using the description of `mutableArray`.

Instead:

```
"Data": mutableArray
```

What you shouldn't do either:
Don't use `NSStuff`, like `NSMutableArray`, prefers Swift one when available: `Swift Array`.

Now, for the representation, what you want is JSON.

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
let jsonStringified = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
print("jsonStringified: \(jsonStringified!)")
```

Be careful, I used try? (didn't do a `catch`), and forced unwrapped `jsonData!` for the sake of showing the logic. You shouldn't do this in final work.

`jsonData`, that's the values that you can put to a `myURLRequest.httpBody = jsonData`, the Stringified is just for debug. If you use `Alamofire` or most of other Third Party HTTP Request Library, they should be okay with just `Parameters`.

Comment: Thanks for replying: I tried the way you said but not worked. I took nsarray and pass as you said but I get the result : ["insert": "0", "Data": (
        {
        "balance_for" = "-517.0";
        "date_list" = "2018/04/23";
        "e_id" = 572;
        "mb_balance" = 35;
        mini = 150;
        "real_earn" = 35;
        "t_depo" = 552;
        "user_id" = 46;
    }
)] I want comma at end not semicolon

Comment: It should work, and you shouln’t use NSArray and you shouldn’t rely on description. Pass the jsonData to your API.

Comment: I am using alamofire and I pass it in parameters

Comment: Then pass parameters to it. It should convert it alone to JSON

Comment: I tried and  it not worked. I dont know why . this is my result : ["insert": "0", "Data": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x60000001dfa0>(
{
    "balance_for" = "18.0";
    "date_list" = "2018/04/23";
    "e_id" = 566;
    "mb_balance" = 34;
    mini = "";
    "real_earn" = 34;
    "t_depo" = 16;
    "user_id" = 46;
}
)
] The was I have to sent in api is this [{"user_id":"46","e_id":"572","date_list":"2018/04/20","t_depo":" 0.0","mini":"40","real_earn":"-5000.0","mb_balance":"-4000.0","balance_for":"4000"}]

Comment: You don"t understand. By giving a Parameters, Alamofire will transform you as JSON (with "no ;  no ="). That's not up to you do construct it.

Comment: Give the code of the Alamofire code. I'd tend to say that's where lies your error.

Comment: ok here is code let parameters: Parameters = ["insert": "0", "Data":  myarray]            do {     Alamofire.request("apilink", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
            {(response) 
                if let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary{
                    let message = json.value(forKey: "message") as! String
                    if message == "Updated Successfully"{
                         print("\(json)")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }